# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on removeFromSuperview Call for Views that are in a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try to remove a UIView that I have previously stored in an NSMutableArray from it's superview. This is the code I'm using:

```
int transRemoveIdx = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < [transparentTiles count]; i++){
    UIView *transparentView = [transparentTiles objectAtIndex:i];
    int transparentViewX = transparentView.frame.origin.x;
    int transparentViewY = transparentView.frame.origin.y;
    NSLog(@"Transparent X: %d Transparent Y: %d", transparentViewX, transparentViewY);

    if(transparentViewX == x && transparentViewY == y && !solid){
        [[transparentTiles objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
        transRemoveIdx = i;
        break;
    }
}
if(transRemoveIdx != -1){
    [transparentTiles removeObjectAtIndex:transRemoveIdx];
}


if(solid){
    [solidTiles addObject:newView];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Adding Tile: %d", tileId);
    [transparentTiles addObject:newView];
}

[mapScroll addSubview:newView];
[mapScroll sendSubviewToBack:newView];
```

This is the initialization of transparentTiles:

```
transparentTiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This checks if a tile has already been placed at the position I want to place it and if it has it will remove the old tile to leave room for the new tile. Or at least that's what I want it to do, however I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error about half the time that `[[transparentTiles objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];` is being called.

I can't figure out when it's going to happen, it seems to be completely random. Is there any way to make sure that this doesn't happen anymore? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**Update:**

I figured out that the only piece of code causing the problem is the removeFromSuperview code. If I were to replace the line

```
[[transparentTiles objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
```

with

```
[[transparentTiles objectAtIndex:i] setAlpha:0.0f];
```

then it all works perfectly. I'm not sure why removeFromSuperview causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS call, but I'm currently setting the alpha of the tile to nothing so it disappears, which essentially accomplishes the same thing that I'm trying to do. Anyone know why a call to removeFromSuperview would cause this error?

Comment: that code alone wouldn't cause that -- 1 where do you add the views and most importantly 2 where do you add them to the array and 3 do you remove the views somewhere else and 4 what kind of array is it (show allocation) AND is there **any multithreading going on?**

Comment: random points to retain release error. A good way to find those bugs  is the Zombies tool in instruments

Comment: @Daij-Djan I edited my post to include the part where I add the tile to the mapScroll and the initialization of the NSMutableArray. There's no multi-threading and I don't remove the views anywhere else.

Comment: please add info on a all the 6 points

Comment: @Daij-Djan 1 & 2 & 3 - Currently the only places that I use transparentTiles are in the post. 4 - NSMutableArray 5 - No Multithreading 6 - I fixed the issue where it does not remove the View from the array when it is removed from the superview, however the error still occurs

Answer (score 1):

from the code you posted it looks like you keep adding tiles but you never remove them.
so the same view can be in the transparentTiles array n times causing n calls to removeFromSuperview? that still shouldn't crash (not without threading) but it is the 1. fishy thing

Answer (score 1):

```
 [transparentTiles removeObjectAtIndex:i];
```

-> this causes your problem. We don't remove object while enumerating the mutable collection.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [transparentTiles count]; i++){
   ...

    if(transparentViewX == x && transparentViewY == y && !solid){
        [[transparentTiles objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview]; //this is the line that causes the error to be called
        [transparentTiles removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Imagine that your transparentTitles had 3 items. The for loop will run for 3 times. If the 'removeObjectAtIndex:i' is executed at 2nd loop turn, at the 3rd loop, the call objectAtIndex:2 will crash cause your transparentTitles has now 2 items instead of 3.

My solution is: add the view to be removed to a another NSMutableArray (ex: _temp), then at the end of your process, remove from your transparentTitles all items exist in _temp

Comment: Another option, depending on whether the supply of tiles is finite and limited, is just to leave all the tiles in the array. Whenever you enumerate through them you can just filter out the ones with superview = null but keep the references around. In some cases that's a handy optimization, in others a giant memory leak, depending on how many tiles there are, how long you want them to stick around, how long this class lives, etc.

Comment: While you are correct, and I changed my code to a better way of doing it this wasn't the issue. I had just added that code (incorrectly) after I had made my post upon Daij-Djan's suggestion. The error still occurs despite my changes however.

Comment: what problem do you have now with current code? It looks OK. Can you post the error or crash log?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you try to access to an object that does not exist.

Comment: Right, which is why I'm confused as to why I'm getting that error since as far as I can tell the object should exist.

Answer (score 0):

Remove like this. So that crash will never happen:-

1)If you want to remove all try below:-

```
[yourVw.subViews performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView:)]
```

2) If you want to remove any particular e.g.

```
for (id vw in yourVw.subViews)
{
if ([vw isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class])
{
[vw removeFromSuperView]
}
}
```